# Call PanResponder methods from another method in React Native

Tags: react-native

Below is the code for the panResponder in componentWillMount() method.

```js
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gesture) => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        this.state.pan.setOffset(this.state.pan.__getValue());
        this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
        Animated.spring(this.state.pan, {toValue: {x:100, y:100}}).start();
      }      
    });
```

How can I call onPanResponderGrant method from a different method?

```js
someMethod = () => {
    // call the pan responder function here
    // this.panResponder.onPanResponderGrant();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just make that function into a method on your component?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(prop)
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gesture) => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: this.onResponderGrant,
    });  
  }
  onResponderGrant = () => {
    this.state.pan.setOffset(this.state.pan.__getValue());
    this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    Animated.spring(this.state.pan, {toValue: {x:100, y:100}}).start();      
  }
}
```

and now you can pass around and call `onResponderGrant()` as you like

Comment: Its giving error message "Cannot read property 'touchHistory' of undefined."

Comment: do you have more code to show? It doesn't look like you're using the `evt` argument, but `touchHistory` is a property on that, the first argument passed to your pan responder methods